# Facebook SDK 4.6.0 FacebookCallback is never called

Tags: android, facebook, share, facebook-android-sdk

In my project there is a possibility to post photo to Facebook using ShareDialog and SharePhotoContent as it represented in [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android). I need to know if posting was successful or not, but onSuccess or onError methods in FacebookCallback implementations are never called.

Here's my code:

```
Button shareFbButton;
ShareDialog shareDialog;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
final int FB_CALLBACK = 101;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(getActivity());
    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.d("photo uri", "FR success: " + result.getPostId());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("photo uri", "FB cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.d("photo uri", "FB error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }, FB_CALLBACK);

    //...
    return alertDialog;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.share_fb_button:
          if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
            SharePhoto photo = new  SharePhoto.Builder()
                                         .setBitmap(image)
                                         .build();
            SharePhotoContent linkContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                         .addPhoto(photo)
                                         .build();

            shareDialog.show(linkContent, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);}
       break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
        if(requestCode == FB_CALLBACK) 
            shareFbButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

I've tried to register callback with REQUEST_CODE and without, but there was no result in both cases.

My build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider933***********1"
        android:exported="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

   <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

I need some help to solve this problem, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.
UPD: ShareDialog and FacebookCallback are implemented in DialogFragment.

Comment: Try this on the sample projects bundled with the SDK. also try with with a) facebook app installed and uninstalled AND b) with publish_actions perm AND without it. Then, if you still believe this is not an issue from your side, then you probably want to create a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an issue in my code. OnActivityResult was called in Activity, not in the DialogFragment. So calling dialogFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) solved the problem.